# Redux how and where to merge objects of two asynchronous calls?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using thunk middleware and I have two asynchronous actions creators like following.

```
export const fetchObject = () => {
return dispatch => {
    let action = fetchObjectRequest();
    dispatch(action);
    let url = "URL1";
    let promise = axios.get(url)
        .then(response => dispatch(fetchObjectSuccess(response.data)));

    return handlingErrorsPromise(promise,
        error => {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
            dispatch(errorOccurred(action, error))
        }
    );
}
```

};

Let's assume I have Object1 and Object 2 endpoints, but the problem is Object1 is required by almost all components and I have to somehow merge all other objects with data from Object1.

Ex: Object2 contains peoples id and I have to attach them names from Object1.

Currently I am mapping my component properties to both objects, and I have if statements in render checking if all object are fetched. Like this:

```
class Peoples extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchObject1();
        this.props.fetchObject2();
    }

    render() {
        let peoples = this.mergeObjects();
        //rendering
    }

    mergeObjects = () => {
        let isFetching = this.props.object1.isFetching ||
            this.props.object2.isFetching;

        if (isFetching) {
            return {
                isFetching,
                json: []
            };
        }
        let mergedJson = {...};
        return {
            isFetching,
            json: mergedJson
        };
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchObject1: () => dispatch(fetchObject1()),
        fetchObject2: () => dispatch(fetchObject2())
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        object1: state.object1,
        object2: state.object2
    };
};

export default Peoples = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Peoples);
```

**Is there a more elegant way to merge one asynchronous object with others in my store?**

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could use the [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) api since axios returns a promise.

```
Promise.all([this.props.fetchObject1(), this.props.fetchObject2()]).then((data) => {
 //do stuff with data
})
```

**Update**:

You can trigger an action in your view `this.props.action.fetchObjects()` that does the `Promise.all` or `yield all[]` if you're using redux-saga and then trigger another action that updates your store with both of them at once (merged or not). You can easily merge them in your view or even in the selector function.

Comment: Ok, but still I have to do this merging on component level.

Comment: This can be done, but the data is not meant to be handled here. It actually comes into the component from the redux state by the props extracted by the `mapStateToProps` function. As the `fetchObjectSuccess` action is dispatched to the store, the connected component will receive new props with the objects. The problem is to know when both objects have been fetched. Waiting for the promises to resolve does not mean that the component already received its new props from the redux store.

Comment: You can easily merge the data inside your middleware (redux-saga, for example) and trigger an action for your reducer to update the store with the merged data. This ensures a single render and only when both promises are resolved.

Comment: I would advocate for keeping the data "raw" in the store, and making needed merges rather in selectors (potentially memoized).

Comment: @PierreKraemer Agreed, i've actually updated my answer to suggest that as well.

Comment: For the record, `dispatch` being synchronous, when the data fetching promises are resolved, the new props have already been received by the component from the store. So you can merge your data here and put the result in the component's state for the next render (which would be better than calling the `mergeObjects` function in the render function itself).